# How can I change to bcrypt instead of md5 in Laravel Auth login check

Tags: laravel, authentication, md5, bcrypt, password-encryption

I am using Hesto/multi-auth

After crearting a new Auth module i was able to register the user but when i am trying to login using same credentials the login attempt is failing. so that i updated the `RegisterController.php->create()` method and changed the password encryption from default `bcrypt` to `md5` (while storing it).then i created another user by registering and then the login was successful.

So to understand this question: 
My laravel version is comparing the 'password' using md5 encryption while login/checking password. But i want to keep using `bcrypt` to register and login (in both use case). how should I change the login method to use `bcrypt` instead of `md5`?

*My Laravel version: 5.5.28*

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return Shopowner::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        //'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'password' => md5($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: are you trying to store data in md5 and login with hash check ? this is two different thing

Comment: I am not trying anything, this is the default Hesto/multi-auth laravel package codes generated. By default, it is using `bcrypt` to store and I am not sure but default laravel Auth mechanism to retrieve the password to attempt login. so I want to tell laravel to use `bcrypt` while retrieving and comparing the password.

Comment: by default laravel use bcrypt to store password , and you can login by Auth::attempt($your_credentials), or get help from Hash::check method

Comment: @EmtiazZahid,  I also want to use `bcrypt` but it's not working if you read my question. if i changed it to md5 while registering as mentioned above then only login attempt is working.

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by "Not able to login"

Comment: @AdlanArifZakaria, simply means login failed scenario occurs. do you want the screen shot with the error message that laravel prints in case of Login failed? Now please some one at least jump beyond understanding just the question. I am feeling like I have written the question not in English but in Hebrew.

Comment: @AdlanArifZakaria, EmtiazZahid, i have updated my question and tried to be more elaborate. let me know if you still not understanding my question and the login flow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My laravel version is comparing the 'password' using md5 encryption
>   while login/checking password. But i want to keep using bcrypt to
>   register and login (in both use case).

In your `config/hashing.php` file, change the driver to `bcrypt`

> how should I change the login method to use bcrypt instead of md5?

In your `RegisterController`, use `Hash::make($data['password']);` instead of `bcrypt` or `md5` functions to ensure that the password is hashed using your driver

Comment: This sounds like an answer, but unfortunately the `config/hashing.php` file is missing in my project. i think the seller has tempered the core of laravel.

Comment: I just checked that this file did not exist in Laravel 5.5 as it only supported one driver (bcrypt). Since you're using 5.5, just making the change in `RegisterController` should work